# "Rogallo wing" balsa rubber-band model plan - do you have one?

Tags: fixed-wing, diy, rubber-band

Several decades ago - 4 or 5 at least - I saw a plan in a model aircraft magazine for a very simple rubber-band driven plane that used a piece of a dry cleaner bag (thin plastic wrap style) as a Rogallo wing.  Wingspan was maybe 2 feet.  Wing spars were simple 3/16" (approx balsa sticks), the body was simple balsa too.  Flew great - I built several back then!

Now, I'd like to experiment with that again and would really like to have some tips - the original plans would be great if someone has a stash or online scan of it in whichever model aircraft magazine it was ... but any information on model-scale Rogallo wings would be useful to get me started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [this plan online](https://www.airplanesandrockets.com/airplanes/images/the-insect-apr-1970-aam-1200x892.jpg), which might be similar to what you want. The wingspan is about right, it uses a Rogallo wing and the text in the bottom-right suggests it was in a magazine called the "American Aircraft Modeler", if that rings any bells? (Your profile indicates America, so it sounded promising.)

[image: Rogallo wing rubber band aircraft from American Aircraft Modeler]

Comment: This is it! i looked a couple of years ago and couldn't find it and thought I'd take a chance on this new stack.  Now my plan is to start building these and varying the wing parameters, do some (limited) science (or at least, engineering ...)